# str_to_felt("pepe token") file "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> nameError: name 'str_to_felt' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, starknet

This is an unexpected error:
str_to_felt("Pepe Token") :
File "", in Line 1, in 
NameError: name 'str_to_felt' is not defined

I haven't tried anything else. The error is not supposed to occur.I am supposed to get an identifying number for my python utility

Comment: Help us help you - share your `import`s

Comment: where is the code ?  the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)